# Sum of cells in a Table

Tags: javascript

I have a table and I want to add cells together

```
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td id="a1">5</td>
      <td id="a2">8</td>
      <td id="a3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="b1"></td>
      <td id="b2"></td>
      <td id="b3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Lets say I want to add a1 and a2 and display the sum in a3 how could I do that in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it'd look something like that (after Jage's suggestion):

```
v_a1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('a1').innerHtml);
v_a2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('a2').innerHtml);
document.getElementById('a3').innerHtml = ( v_a1 + v_a2 );
```

Answer (score 4):

Just pull the DOM objects by their ID and get the numerical contents and add them together. Then take your new sum and fill the contents in the 3rd cell. I would also search that by ID. You may want to account for NaN if you care about the visible output.

Comment: Ok I got them to add but how do I display it in the 3rd cell?

Comment: Pretty much the same. Find the DOM object, and then instead of get the contents, set the contents.